# CMake link library from find_package with system lib in wrong order

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command, find-package

my CMakeLists.txt is as follows

```
find_pacakge(something)
add_executable(exe main.cc)
# libsomething depends on dlopen/dlsym... so I have to add dl here
target_link_libraries(run PRIVATE something::something dl)
```

results:

```
g++ -o exe -ldl path/to/libsomething.a
libsomething.c: undefined reference to `dlsym'
```

but CMake always put the -ldl flag before libsomething.a even I have tried:

```
target_link_libraries(run PRIVATE dl something::something dl something::something )

# produced output:
# g++ -o exe -ldl -ldl path/to/libsomething.a
# libsomething.c: undefined reference to `dlsym'
```

or

```
target_link_libraries(run PRIVATE dl)
target_link_libraries(run PRIVATE something::something)
target_link_libraries(run PRIVATE dl)

# produced output:
# g++ -o exe -ldl -ldl path/to/libsomething.a
# libsomething.c: undefined reference to `dlsym'
```

But the right way to build the program is

```bash
$ g++ -o exe path/to/libsomething.a -ldl
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: For improving platform independency I suggest using `${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}` instead of adding plain `dl`. Did you cleared the CMake cache (delete CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles folder in build directory) after doing the changes and before rerunning CMake?

Comment: BTW, the `target_link_libraries` command should be applied to the `exe` target, not `run`.

Comment: Thanks. "run" It's my typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment

> `# libsomething depends on dlopen/dlsym... so I have to add dl here`

reveals the **core** of the problem: It is `libsomething` needs linkage with `dl`, so its `find_package(something)` should care about that. The absence of that linkage is a deficiency (that is, a bug) in the **library itself**.

If you are the author of the library, then fix it.
If the author of the library accepts bugreports, then fill the one about given problem.

If fixing the library is not an option for you, then you could "fix" result of `find_package` in your project:

```
find_package(something)
# Created imported target misses linkage with 'dl' library.
# Add it here.
target_link_libraries(something::something INTERFACE ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})

add_executable(exe main.cc)
# Now we can use the library in a simple way
target_link_libraries(exe PRIVATE something::something)
```

The above code relies on the fact, that `something::something`, provided by `find_package(something)`, is an IMPORTED target, denoting the library file. So we can add required linkage to it.

Comment: I think you are right.